# Sequence equivalent research

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

I'm studying this series:

[image]

I know that there is this relation:

[image]

[image]

($\ell$ is the common limit of the two series)

Do you know a *Mathematica* function that could prove this relation?

Comment: You should look at `RSolve` , although on first pass it doesn't seem to be able to solve this.

Comment: I think you need a0,b0 to have the same sign BTW.

Comment: Yes a0 and b0 are > 0. But, did you manage to have the result?

Comment: @george2079 I had a new picture with a new relation that might help.

Comment: I confirmed your result numerically. That's not a proof though.  re: edit you should see what `RSolve` does with that.

Comment: These are the recursion relations for the [`arithmetic-harmonic mean`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-HarmonicMean.html) and the limits are the [`geometric mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricMean.html)

Comment: Could you please tell me what formula you wrote in Mathematica? I began Mathematica one day ago, and I can't find any interesting result with RSolve. The thing is on the internet, each time they use RSolve, there is only one function. Here, there is (a) and (b) ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof but rather an empirical test

```
Clear[a, b]

#[{a, b}] & /@ {Mean, HarmonicMean, GeometricMean}

(* {(a + b)/2, 2/(1/a + 1/b), Sqrt[a b]} *)
```

Since the terms converge, then you can used [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) to find the limit

```
gm[a_?Positive, b_?Positive] :=
 FixedPoint[{Mean[#], HarmonicMean[#]} &, {a, b}]
```

Testing whether the limits are the same and equal to the [`GeometricMean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricMean.html) for 10,000 pairs of random reals

```
And @@ Table[
  {a, b} = RandomReal[{10^-9, 100}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 15];
  g = gm[a, b];
  g[[1]] == g[[2]] == GeometricMean[{a, b}],
  {10000}]

(* True *)
```

You can use [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) to look at the convergence step-by-step

```
FixedPointList[{Mean[#], HarmonicMean[#]} &, {5., 79.}]

(* {{5., 79.}, {42., 9.40476}, {25.7024, 15.3682}, {20.5353, 19.2352}, 
    {19.8852, 19.864}, {19.8746, 19.8746}, {19.8746, 19.8746}, 
    {19.8746, 19.8746}, {19.8746, 19.8746}} *)

GeometricMean[{5., 79.}]

(* 19.8746 *)
```

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t understand how it demonstrate the equality that I have to show ?

Comment: This shows that the common limit of the two series is the `GeometricMean`, i.e., `l = Sqrt[a0*b0]`